# How to add a line at x=y to a contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I cant figure out how to add a line to my contour plot at x=y.

```
epsilon_1= np.linspace(1,25,1000)
epsilon_2= np.linspace(1,25,1000)
eps1, eps2 = np.meshgrid( epsilon_1, epsilon_2 )
plt.contourf( eps1, eps2, E, 100 ,cmap="jet")
```

is what I have and I'm not sure how to add this line if its even possible?

I wasn't sure what to try.

Comment: You can add an infinite diagonal line via `plt.axline(xy1=(0, 0), slope=1, ls=':', lw=2, color='k')`. You can use `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')` to make the x and y axes equal, which will show the line at 45º.